# Run ServiceConnection in default main thread or separately

Tags: android, android-service

In [Android's developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) for class `ServiceConnection`, it is written:

> Interface for monitoring the state of an application service. See
>   android.app.Service and Context.bindService() for more information. 
>   Like many callbacks from the system, the methods on this class are
>   called from the main thread of your process.

Now, in my application, I'm running a `ServiceConnection` as soon as the Main Activity starts and spans over the entire lifecycle of the application, till it exits.

So, from the remark the methods on this class are called from the main thread of your process, I'm wondering, if main thread means UI thread, and if yes, then:

1. Should I code this `ServiceConnection`, in a thread separate from UI thread. (How?)
2. Or, should I continue using it as I'm doing it right now. i.e. within the MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, Android's "main thread" and "UI thread" are one and the same and the event methods which comprise the connection will be called on that thread.  If you want to do things in response which should be done on another thread, you'll need to have those event methods use one of the various mechanisms for pushing work to another thread.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks. Can u help with an example?